# PHP usort Multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, usort

I'm having trouble getting usort to work and not sure what I'm missing.  Below is an example of my array.  I want to sort the array based on the value of the sort key.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [sort] => 1520546956
        [row] => Data lives here
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [sort] => 1521047928
        [row] => Data lives here
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [sort] => 1520525366
        [row] => Data lives here
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [sort] => 1520525227
        [row] => Data lives here
    )
```

My code to try and sort this is:

```
foreach ($resultsArray as $record)
{
    usort($record['sort'], function($a, $b)
        {
            if ($a == $b)
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;  
        });
}
```

However my code seems to be ineffective as the order of the array isn't changing.  I feel like I'm close but can't identify what I'm missing.  Thank you for any help!

Comment: `$record` will be a copy of the array element, not a reference. Thus, any changes you make to the element will not persist. To fix this, either do `foreach($resultsArray as $index=>$record)` and then `$resultsArray[$index] = $record` after sorting, or do `foreach($resultsArray as &$record)`--note the `&` in this second example!

Comment: Additionally, your sort logic itself is off. `usort` sorts the given array in place. Thus, `$record['sort']` should be an array. If you want to use `usort` properly, do `usort($resultsArray, function($a, $b) { /* compare $a['sort'] and $b['sort'] */ }`! This will completely avoid the need for a `foreach` loop.

Comment: @B.Fleming That did the trick - ending up going with `usort($resultsArray, function($a, $b) { /* compare $a['sort'] and $b['sort'] */ }` and working correctly now.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A different approach to accomplish the same functionality is to use [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) with the desired combination of sorting flags.

Dataset:

```
$resultsArray = array(
  array('sort'=>1520546956, 'row'=>'row 0 data'),
  array('sort'=>1521047928, 'row'=>'row 1 data'),
  array('sort'=>1520525366, 'row'=>'row 2 data'),
  array('sort'=>1520525227, 'row'=>'row 3 data')
);
```

`array_multisort` Example:

```
$sortValues = array_column($resultsArray, 'sort');
array_multisort($sortValues, SORT_ASC, $resultsArray);
print_r($resultsArray);
```

Results: https://3v4l.org/NpVIc

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sort] => 1520525227
            [row] => row 3 data
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [sort] => 1520525366
            [row] => row 2 data
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [sort] => 1520546956
            [row] => row 0 data
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [sort] => 1521047928
            [row] => row 1 data
        )

)
```

---

Alternatively you can still use [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), but in your function, you need to retrieve the associated array key named `sort` in order to compare the values.

usort Example:

```
usort($resultsArray, function($a, $b) { 
    if ($a['sort'] == $b['sort']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['sort'] < $b['sort'] ? -1 : 1);
});
print_r($resultsArray);
```

Results: https://3v4l.org/5nfbc

Answer (score 0):

Modified code to reflect the below as suggested:

```
usort($resultsArray, function($a, $b) { /* compare $a['sort'] and $b['sort'] */ }
```

Working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

`$record['sort']` would have to be an array for that to work. Yet still, it does nothing.

I'm pretty sure you want to do this:

```
<?php
$multiArray = array(
  array('sort'=>1520546956, 'row'=>'row 0 data'),
  array('sort'=>1521047928, 'row'=>'row 1 data'),
  array('sort'=>1520525366, 'row'=>'row 2 data'),
  array('sort'=>1520525227, 'row'=>'row 3 data'));
foreach($multiArray as $a){
  $numArray[] = $a['sort'];
}
asort($numArray, SORT_NUMERIC);
foreach($numArray as $k => $v){
  $resArray[] = $multiArray[$k];
}
print_r($resArray);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because php foreach construct works on the copy of the array provided(ie: $resultsArray), where php usort() function references or points to the same array. That is why your code is not working as expected. 
If you don't understand this concept I suggest you a good online course by Kevin skoglund (php essential training) in Lynda.com

Comment: @Oighea I have not asked any question but have answered it. clarify what you are trying to say.

Comment: It isn't grammatically correct. Proper grammar is required since this isn't a chat room nor an informal discussion board.